# To stop detail records deleted whenever master records deleted

Tags: relationships

Is is possible to stop the details records being deleted whenever corresponding master record deleted?  If so can you pls provide solution.

Answer (score 2):

When the parent record in a master detail relationship is deleted, its related detail records are also deleted.  By default, records can’t be reparented in master-detail relationships. Administrators can, however, allow child records in master-detail relationships on custom objects to be reparented to different parent records by selecting the Allow reparenting option in the master-detail relationship definition.  You could write a trigger to reparent child records prior to deletion of the parent record.

Reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/relationships_among_objects.htm